# using a storyboard from another project

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I am working on an Iphone Application, and I want to get a storyboard from another project.

I added the storyboard and all the viewcontrollers and images to my project (I copy Paste them from the other project)

Then I set it as the main storyboard in the info,plist file.

I get no compile errors or warnings however if I try to run the project I get a `signal SIGABRT` error.

(If i return to my original storyboard the app runs normally)

Any idea what might be causing the problem?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Did you copy to project location or just reference it. I have some trouble sometimes just referencing stuff.

Comment: I copy to project location. I copy pasted the files to the finder then drag dropped them into my project and checked "Copy items into destinations group's folder" and chose "Create groups for any added folders"

Comment: Are you calling the Controllers correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wired all storyboard object to proper ViewController ?
I often forget wiring delegate =)

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

In the summary tab make sure that the main storyboard is selected under "project name"/summery/ iPhone/iPod deployment info